# advice on refreshing incoming messages with mt_rand()?

Tags: php

is this a good way of doing it? or should i use a date time stamp with seconds rather?

while i am on a page, the new message must come through without me refreshing the page

my code is written in php:

```
<div id='div_longgray_gradient2'>
<div id='div_float_img'>
<table width='96%' border='0'>
<tr>
    <td rowspan='2' width='40px' align='left'>

        <img src='/images/rainbow/arrow.png'>
    </td>

    <td align='left'>
        <span class='spn_big_black_rbc'>MESSAGES</span>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align='left'>
        <span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>Inbox</span>    
    </td>
    <td align='left'>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>

<table width='80%' align='center'>
<tr>
    <td class='td_show_contact_heading' align='left'><span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>Received</span></td>
    <td class='td_show_contact_heading' align='left'><span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>Message</span></td>
    <td class='td_show_contact_heading' align='left'><span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>From</span></td>
</tr>
<?php 
$cursor = $pager->getFirstIndice(); 
foreach ($pager->getResults() as $msg)
{ 
$has_freechat = false;  
//changed id to withid here
$freechat_req_link="profiles/confirmfreechat?withid=".$msg->getRcProfileTableRelatedByProfileIdFrom()->getId();
$freechat_req_link=link_to('Freechat',$freechat_req_link,'class=link_small_dark');

$cc = sizeof ($fc_records);
for($i = 0; $i < $cc; $i++) 
{
    if($fc_records[$i]->getProfileIdWith() == $msg->getProfileIdFrom())
    {       
        $has_freechat = true;       
        break;
    }
}   

$unique_code_from = $msg->getRcProfileTableRelatedByProfileIdFrom()->getUniqueCode();
$block_url = link_to('Block User',"blocklist/block?unqiue_code=$unique_code_from",'class=link_medium_blue');
echo "<tr>";
$date = add_date($msg->getCreatedAt(),$hr=2);
echo "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left'>".$date."</td>";
$opened_once = $msg->getOpenedOnce();
if($opened_once >= 1)
{
   echo "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left'>".link_to($msg->getSubject(),   'messagebox/read?cursor='.$cursor,'class=link_medium_blue')."</td>";
}    
else
{ ?>
   <td align='left'>
     <a href="<?php echo url_for('messagebox/read?cursor=').$cursor ?>" style='color:#ff0000 !important' class='spn_small_red_rbc'><?php echo $msg->getSubject();?></a>        
   </td>      
<?php 
} 
echo "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left'>".$unique_code_from." ( $block_url )</td>";
echo "</tr>";
++$cursor; 
}

function add_date($givendate,$hr=2)
{
$cd = strtotime($givendate);
$newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(date('h',$cd)+$hr, date('i',$cd), date('s',$cd), date('m',$cd), date('d',$cd), date('Y',$cd)));
return $newdate;
}
?>
</table>
<br/>
Displaying results <?php echo $pager->getFirstIndice() ?> to  <?php echo $pager->getLastIndice() ?>.
<br/>

<?php if ($pager->haveToPaginate()): ?>

<?php echo link_to('&laquo;', 'messagebox/list?page='.$pager->getFirstPage()) ?>
<?php echo link_to('&lt;', 'messagebox/list?page='.$pager->getPreviousPage()) ?>
<?php $links = $pager->getLinks(); foreach ($links as $page): ?>
<?php echo ($page == $pager->getPage()) ? $page : link_to($page, 'messagebox/list?page='.$page) ?>
<?php if ($page != $pager->getCurrentMaxLink()): ?> - <?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php echo link_to('&gt;', 'messagebox/list?page='.$pager->getNextPage()) ?>
<?php echo link_to('&raquo;', 'messagebox/list?page='.$pager->getLastPage()) ?>
<?php endif ?>

<table width='96%' border='0'>
<tr> 
    <td rowspan='2' width='40px' align='left'> 
        <img src='/images/rainbow/arrow.png'> 
    </td> 
    <td align='left'> 
        <span class='spn_big_black_rbc'></span> 
    </td> 
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td align='left'>
        <span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>Sent Items</span>   
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<table width='80%' align='center'>
<tr>
    <td class='td_show_contact_heading' align='left'><span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>Sent</span></td>
    <td class='td_show_contact_heading' align='left'><span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>Message</span></td>
    <td class='td_show_contact_heading' align='left'><span class='spn_med_lightblue_rbc'>To</span></td>
</tr>
<?php
$cursor2 = $pager2->getFirstIndice(); 
$br = sizeof ($block_records);
foreach ($pager2->getResults() as $item)
{ 
    $link = link_to('Delete',"messagebox/deleteSentmsg?mid=".$item->getId(),'class=link_medium_blue');
    $id = $item->getRcProfileTableRelatedByProfileIdTo()->getId();    
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class='td_show_contact_item' width='15%' align='left'><?php echo $date = add_date($item->getCreatedAt(),$hr=2); ?></td>
        <td class='td_show_contact_item' width='45%' align='left'><?php echo $item->getMessage()?></td>
        <td class='td_show_contact_item' width='25%' align='left'><?php echo $item->getRcProfileTableRelatedByProfileIdTo()->getUniqueCode()."  ".$link;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
     ++$cursor2;    
}
?>
</table>
<br/>
Displaying results <?php echo $pager2->getFirstIndice(); ?> to  <?php echo $pager2->getLastIndice(); ?>.
<br/>
<?php if ($pager2->haveToPaginate()): ?>
<?php echo link_to('&laquo;', 'messagebox/list?page2='.$pager2->getFirstPage(),'class=link_big_dark') ?>
<?php echo link_to('&lt;', 'messagebox/list?page2='.$pager2->getPreviousPage(),'class=link_big_dark') ?>
<?php $links = $pager2->getLinks(); foreach ($links as $page2): ?>
<?php echo ($page2 == $pager2->getPage()) ? $page2 : link_to($page2, 'messagebox/list?page2='.$page2,'class=link_big_dark') ?>
<?php if ($page2 != $pager2->getCurrentMaxLink()): ?> - <?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php echo link_to('&gt;', 'messagebox/list?page2='.$pager2->getNextPage(),'class=link_big_dark') ?>
<?php echo link_to('&raquo;', 'messagebox/list?page2='.$pager2->getLastPage(),'class=link_big_dark') ?>
<?php endif ?>
</div>
</div>
```

can anyone give some advise please?
i have no ajax/JS here so dont know how i would incorporate it

Comment: Can you possibly give a little more background on what you're trying to do here?

Comment: i am working on a website where, once you are registered, you can log in and send somebody a message, this person must be in your contacts list. people can send each other messages via the website. while on the messages page(see the code above, it lists all messages received) the message must come through, without the person clicking on the refresh button to see if the other person sent a message. unfortunately this webpage is only hosted in my country...so giving the url wont help :( 

hope this helps?

thank you

Comment: What I don't understand is what the specific question is and how `mt_rand` and/or the timestamp are related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server side language and will not update a page once it has been fetched by the browser. To do this you will need to use a combination of server side and client side scripts.

One way of making your page update it's content is to use AJAX (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) combined with a timer (setInterval() and setTimeout()) to query a PHP script and check for updates every x seconds. The updates can then be added to the page when they are available using JavaScript / jQuery.

Comment: exactly what i was thinking but have no idea how to code this? i have just started on some ajax tutorials but struggling though...can you help me out please? i will post all my code for this page at the top

thank you!

Comment: Try to code it yourself, start by following a basic tutorial and working up. If you have more questions first search Google and stackoverflow to see if they have been asked before, if all else fails create a new question but be specific and give relevant code examples relating to what you have tried and what you are trying to do.

Comment: i have the JS in place(function gethttprequest() , function getNewMessage and function handleResponse(), added a <body onload="getNewMessage()"> and a <div id='message_area'>, i also added alerts in all 3 functions to see if the code executes but it gets as far as the httprequest function...doesn look like the onload is calling getNewMessage...will ask new question, have gone though tutorials but struggling though!  thank you!